# I want to upload document [img /txt / doc....]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating automation script ..i dont want to click on browse and upload button.
I want to set local file path and upload to server the doc.

here is the code ...is there any script/code i can do that

```
   <input id="ctl00_pagePlaceHolder_ajaxFU_file" type="file" name="ctl00$pagePlaceHolder$ajaxFU$file" class="fileupload" style="cursor:pointer;">
<a onclick="UploadFilectl00_pagePlaceHolder_ajaxFU(); return false;" id="ctl00_pagePlaceHolder_ajaxFU_visibleUploadButton" class="btn -blue -smaller" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$pagePlaceHolder$ajaxFU$visibleUploadButton','')" style="margin-left:4px;">Upload</a>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$pagePlaceHolder$ajaxFU$hiddenUploadButton" value="" id="ctl00_pagePlaceHolder_ajaxFU_hiddenUploadButton" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

use selenium for automation and file uploading

[getttingstart](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

you dont need to click on browser few steps will help you

Comment: do you have any example here ?

Comment: yes here is 
WebDriver driver=new FireFoxBrowser();
driver.get("you url");
driver.findElementById("ctl00_pagePlaceHolder_ajaxFU_file").sendKeys("your file path");

/*then click upload */
driver.findElementById("ctl00_pagePlaceHolder_ajaxFU_visibleUploadButton").click();

you need to define the path of file you want to upload

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload the file automatically - a user has to first select a file.

Otherwise it would be a security issue - imagine you visit a site and all of a sudden it starts uploading documents from your local hard disk without your knowledge.

Comment: @Sr.QARats what do you mean?

Comment: I mean ...Set  file location and JavaScript  code for click on upload button ...I want to know how to set